# Ingresar secuencia de Fibonacci en Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando escribir un código que pida uno por uno, y en orden los primeros 6 números de la famosa secuencia de Fibonacci.

No quiero que el algoritmo genere los números, lo que quiero es que verifique que son correctos, y están en el orden correcto.

He intentado varios métodos, pero tan solo me he acercado a la solución, hasta ahora, nada definitivo.

Este es el ultimo método que estoy intentando.

```
Fib = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
Fib2 = []
A, B = 0, 1
while A < 9:
    A = input("Ingresar número Fibonacci")
    if int(A) in Fib:
        A, B = int(B), int(A) + int(B)
        Fib2.append(B)
    else:
        print("Incorrecto")
print("OK")
print(Fib2)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

se crea un variable donde se almacenara las secuencias previas tanto para ayudar a no tener que calcular los numeros previos por cada iteracion y para ser utilizado en la comparación de los números escritos! "eficiencia"!

```
# almacenara los resultados previos
memory = {}

# definimos funcion
def fibo(n):
    # creamos una vaibale value
    value= None

    # en caso de que envien 0
    if n == 0:
        return False
    # si el numero ya esta almacenado en cache lo retorna
    if n in memory:
        return memory[n]

    # si el numero == 1 o ==2 
    if n == 1 or n ==2:
        value=1

    else:
        # recursividad
        value = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)

    # almacenamos en cahe el resultado del numero
    memory[n]= value
    # retornamos valor
    return value

# rellenamos el cache con 100
for x in range(1,100):
    #print(x , ": " ,fibo(x))
    fibo(x)


# contador
c = 1
# correctas
ok = 0
# cantidad de preguntas
l = 9
while c < l:
    res = None;
    n = input("Ingresar número Fibonacci en la posicion: {} ".format(c))
    if int(n) == memory[c]:
        res="correcto!"
        # aumentamos la respuestas correctas
        ok = ok+1
    else:
        res="incorrecto"
    print(res)
    # aumentamos el contador
    c=c+1

print("respuestas correctas: {} \n respuestas incorrectas: {}".format(ok,l-ok))
```